# Upload file using Flash uploaders - what is size limit?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I plan to use some of Flash uploaders for uploading large files (2Gb-8Gb). Is there any limit on upload file size Flash Player can handle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Flash has a hardcoded file upload limit. However, keep in mind the place you are uploading it to may place restrictions (ie your web server). Also, it is better to upload in parts if possible or if your power goes off or something, you're going to have to start again.

Comment: It seems there are some limitations in Flash player itself: http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/584

Comment: If there was, I'm pretty sure it's more server sided. I found http://www.filedropper.com/ as an example. It uses a Flash uploader and supports up to 5 GB.

Comment: I've tried 3.5Gb files on filedropper.com -- their flash uploader dies immediately (I'm on Windows7 32bit, Firefox, Flash Player 10.1)

Comment: Perhaps it's a limit to 32 bit (2 GB). Using 64 bit, I was able to start the upload progress of a 4 GB file.